# Unity Instantiate command not working properly

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation, game-development

Whenever I try to Instantiate a particle system in Unity 3D the command positions the particles but doesn't play/runs the animation.

HEre's my code

```
GameObject impactGO = Instantiate(impactEffect, hit.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal));
Destroy(impactGO, sleep_);
```

> Unity version-2021.1.1f1

Comment: You should explicitly call `Play` on the particle system, Or set `playOnAwake` to true before activate the particle. And make sure `sleep_` is large enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Positions the particles, but doesn't play/run the animation

If the particle system  is instantiated by your code successful, which it seems to do. There are multiple ways to ensure it start when it's created.

---

**Play on Awake:**

Then you need to ensure that the particle system has [`Play On Awake`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysMainModule.html) set to `enabled`. As this will ensure the particle system starts playing as soon as you create it in your scene.

[image: Particle System Main module]

---

**ParticleSystem.Play Altnertive:**

Alternatively you can use the [`ParticleSystem.Play`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.Play.html) function to start the particle system in code after you've created it.

```cs
ParticleSystem impactPS = Instantiate(impactEffect, hit.point, 
    Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal)) as ParticleSystem;
impactPS.Play();
Destroy(impactPS.gameObjkect, sleep_);
```

---

**Getting Duration of Particle System:**

Additionally if you want to get the duration of your particle system you can use `.main.duration`. To ensure you don't destroy your `gameObject` before the particle system has finished playing.

```cs
float sleep_ = impactPS.main.duration;
```